# Take a screenshot of X display from SSH

Tags: import, imagemagick

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a particular X display with imagemagick using the following syntax :

```
import -window root -geometry 640:480 -display :9999 myfile01.pcx
```

So taking the screenshot of root at display :999, but i get a :

```
import: unable to open X server `:9999' @ import.c/ImportImageCommand/367.
```

I'm logged in with SSH, is it possible? what am i doing wrong?

To be more precise, it's not really X, it's a VNC server (launched by :

```
usr/local/bin/Xvnc :9999 -desktop client:9999 (9999) -auth /home/9999/.Xauthority -geometry 1024x768 -depth 24 -rfbwait 30000 -rfbauth /home/9999/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 9901 -fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc -pn -rfbauth /home/9999/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 9999 -alwaysshared +kb -desktop CyberUser[9999]
```

Comment: I suppose you're sure that the used display is indeed `:9999`. What's the result of `scrot` (http://scrot.sourcearchive.com) over SSH, if you're able to install that.

Comment: Ok, edited the post. I've tried vncsnapshot but it also gives me a "Connection Refused" error, i've added a "xhost +" in xstartup also, no clue ...

Comment: scrot over ssh gives : "giblib error: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?"

Comment: Hmm, that's the same warning I get when running scrot from a console screen. Sorry, can't help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make your screenshot while using the `-Y` commandline param to ssh:

```
 ssh -Y user@remote "DISPLAY=:9999 import -window root \
     -geometry 640:480 -display :9999 myfile01.pcx"
```